# Como puedo mostrar el contenido de un array de json en angular?

Tags: json, angular, api, mongodb

estoy listando las horas agendadas de un usuario desde una api, necesito mostrar el nombre de ese usuario, pero obtengo [object Object]
esto recibo por consola

```
createdAt: "2022-02-22T20:04:08.959Z"
doctorId: Array(1)
0: {_id: '6213e6c2d887e1663b74faa5', nameUser: 'doctor', password: 
'$2a$10$Uig9O/zHF6wH7YxSLi0NKeV081a9puRxfaVoUhexYdB60LlzoP5Ny', organization: 'Centro suyai', 
ocupation: 'medicina general', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
hourEnd: "2033-03-29T16:34:00.000Z"
hourStart: "2010-03-29T16:34:00.000Z"
```

y se lista el get

```
<tr *ngFor="let horarios of horariosService.horarios">

  <td>{{ horarios.hourStart }}</td>
  <td>{{ horarios.hourEnd }}</td>
  <div ng-repeat=" asd in horarios "> {{horarios.doctorId}}
     </div>
```

Comment: para mayor claridad podrias mostrar la estrctura del objeto la llamada a la API y como manejas la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, estas queriendo mostrar `doctorId`, pero por lo que pones, es un array. Asumiendo que el usuario que buscas siempre esta en la primera posicion de ese array, deberias hacer `horarios.doctorId[0].nameUser`